# How to copy files from a debian 9 google cloud vm to my local windows 10 machine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Am trying to copy directories/files from a google cloud VM instance with debian 9 OS to my windows 10 laptop. Which command should I use? Trying to download from the google console is not working. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If the VM supports and has ssh active, you might be able to exchange files using the windows WinSCP application.

Answer (score 1):

As described in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files), you can transfer files between your Windows Worstation and the Linux VM instance three different ways:

- Cloud Storage
- gcloud compute scp
- WinSCP

I would suggest going through the attached article and see which way transferring files suits your needs best.